# Creating a custom Swift Package with a Firebase plist resource file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift-package-manager

I have a custom Swift Package that contains all my firebase/firestore code.  All good.  Only issue is the required Google plist that needs to be included.  I've tried including the following code in my package manifest file:

```swift
 targets: [
        .target(
            name: "myCustomPackage",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "FirebaseFirestoreSwift-Beta", package: "Firebase"),
                .product(name: "FirebaseAuth", package: "Firebase"),
            ],
            path: "Sources",
            resources: [
                .process("GoogleService-Info.plist")
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "myCustomPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["myCustomPackageTests"], path: "Tests"),
    ]
```

This all works and the plist file is part of the package.

In then another project, I add myCustomPackage and that all works and compiles.  But if I go to access any firebase services, the app crashes with the following error:

`FirebaseApp.configure() could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.`

I don't understand as the GoogleService-Info.plist file is there.  Any ideas on what step I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean 'there'?  Is it imported to your Xcode project?

Comment: If I look at the files under Package Dependencies (in the Project Navigator on Xcode), it lists the Package and in that package, there are a number of files.  One of those is the GoogleService-Info.plist file.  So it is there.

Comment: Does the bundle identifier of your app matches that of the one indicated in Google guy's info.plist?  Just out of curiocity...

Comment: Good point.  If I create a new iOS app in the Firebase console and generate a new plist file, add that to the new project, then it works.